# why do I have requests from inside apache server with source ports 80 and 443

Tags: apache-httpd, firewall, http, https, shorewall

On one machine, I have a web server running (apache) and responding on ports 80 and 443. On this machine, I have a firewall (shorewall) that blocks everything except what I authorize, and I therefore have the following rules (I have many others, but which are off topic here, so I keep it simple):

```
?SECTION NEW
Web(ACCEPT) net fw
Web(ACCEPT) fw net
```

Everything works perfectly. EXCEPT that in the firewall logs, I realize that I have lots of outgoing requests rejected with SOURCE ports 80 and 443. And I don't understand why these requests are sent or why rejecting them is not at all blocking the operation of the web server.

Note that I have exactly the same question with the mail server and ports 25,110,143,465,993,995.

I'm trying to understand, not necessarily to correct something if it's not useful.

**EDIT:**

Question asked on the shorewall mailing list and it is confirmed that everything is normal, that this corresponds to connections already closed, and that to no longer see these lines appear in the logs, I just need to add dropInvalid to the

```
REJECT_DEFAULT="Broadcast(DROP),Multicast(DROP)"
```

configured by default in Shorewall

But that doesn't work at all. Whatever I put in REJECT_DEFAULT, I always have these lines in my logs.

**EDIT2:**

`iptables-save -c` asked in comments (I removed all fail2ban rules):

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.9 on Fri Oct 27 16:43:40 2023
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [294959:300247330]
:INPUT ACCEPT [294959:300247330]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [271994:270207145]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [271932:270200193]
[0:0] -A FORWARD -j MARK --set-xmark 0x0/0xff
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Oct 27 16:43:40 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.9 on Fri Oct 27 16:43:40 2023
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [22019:1019969]
:INPUT ACCEPT [10536:410458]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [9493:687413]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [9493:685796]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Oct 27 16:43:40 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.9 on Fri Oct 27 16:43:40 2023
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [294959:300247330]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [271994:270207145]
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Oct 27 16:43:40 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.9 on Fri Oct 27 16:43:40 2023
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:dynamic - [0:0]
:eth0_fwd - [0:0]
:eth0_in - [0:0]
:fw-net - [0:0]
:logdrop - [0:0]
:logflags - [0:0]
:logreject - [0:0]
:reject - [0:0]
:sfilter - [0:0]
:sha-lh-1550d655e9a1cad182eb - [0:0]
:sha-rh-dee8631b410018e6f7d8 - [0:0]
:shorewall - [0:0]
:sshok-fw - [0:0]
:tcpflags - [0:0]
:~log0 - [0:0]
:~log1 - [0:0]
:~log2 - [0:0]
:~log3 - [0:0]
:~log4 - [0:0]
[287639:299139087] -A INPUT -i eth0 -j eth0_in
[1702:777139] -A INPUT -m iface --dev-in --loopback  -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -g ~log2
[0:0] -A INPUT -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 1/sec --hashlimit-burst 10 --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name lograte -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT REJECT " --log-level 6
[0:0] -A INPUT -g reject
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j eth0_fwd
[0:0] -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -g ~log4
[0:0] -A FORWARD -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 1/sec --hashlimit-burst 10 --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name lograte -j LOG --log-prefix "FORWARD REJECT " --log-level 6
[0:0] -A FORWARD -g reject
[270273:269429246] -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j fw-net
[1721:777899] -A OUTPUT -m iface --dev-out --loopback  -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -g ~log3
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 1/sec --hashlimit-burst 10 --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name lograte -j LOG --log-prefix "OUTPUT REJECT " --log-level 6
[0:0] -A OUTPUT -g reject
[0:0] -A eth0_fwd -o eth0 -g sfilter
[0:0] -A eth0_fwd -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID,NEW,UNTRACKED -j dynamic
[0:0] -A eth0_fwd -p tcp -j tcpflags
[16554:699778] -A eth0_in -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID,NEW,UNTRACKED -j dynamic
[261014:296956611] -A eth0_in -p tcp -j tcpflags
[148579:24762560] -A eth0_in -m set --match-set sshok src -j sshok-fw
[123729:273762557] -A eth0_in -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[1120:52679] -A eth0_in -m geoip --source-country CN,RU  -g ~log1
[651:51460] -A eth0_in -s MyIP -j ACCEPT
[8233:263993] -A eth0_in -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m comment --comment Ping -j ACCEPT
[1139:63657] -A eth0_in -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587,143,993,110,995,80,443 -m comment --comment "Mail, IMAP, IMAPS, POP3, POP3S, Web" -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A eth0_in -s MyIP -p tcp -m multiport --dports 9418,8000,9101:9102 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A eth0_in -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j DROP
[0:0] -A eth0_in -m addrtype --dst-type ANYCAST -j DROP
[0:0] -A eth0_in -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j DROP
[4837:233521] -A eth0_in -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 1/sec --hashlimit-burst 10 --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name lograte -j LOG --log-prefix "net-fw DROP " --log-level 6
[4837:233521] -A eth0_in -j DROP
[253629:268207796] -A fw-net -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A fw-net -m geoip --destination-country CN,RU  -g ~log0
[1:60] -A fw-net -d MyIP -p tcp -m multiport --dports 9101:9103,19101:19103,19112,19122 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A fw-net -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 2 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A fw-net -p udp -m udp --dport 33434:33524 -m comment --comment Trcrt -j ACCEPT
[138:11592] -A fw-net -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m comment --comment Trcrt -j ACCEPT
[14996:1113778] -A fw-net -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m comment --comment DNS -j ACCEPT
[1311:78660] -A fw-net -p tcp -m multiport --dports 53,22,80,443,21,25,465,587 -m comment --comment "DNS, SSH, HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, Mail" -j ACCEPT
[118:8968] -A fw-net -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -m comment --comment NTP -j ACCEPT
[4:240] -A fw-net -p tcp -m multiport --dports 43,4321,2703 -m comment --comment "Whois and others, Razor" -j ACCEPT
[2:384] -A fw-net -d 154.61.86.89/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 24441 -j ACCEPT
[12:816] -A fw-net -p udp -m udp --dport 6277 -m comment --comment DCC -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A fw-net -p tcp -m tcp --dport 873 -m comment --comment Rsync -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A fw-net -d 187.33.4.179/32 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A fw-net -p tcp -m multiport --dports 8000,8001,8080,8276 -j ACCEPT
[43:1804] -A fw-net -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -g ~log0
[19:5148] -A fw-net -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 1/sec --hashlimit-burst 10 --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name lograte -j LOG --log-prefix "fw-net REJECT " --log-level 6
[19:5148] -A fw-net -g reject
[0:0] -A logdrop -j DROP
[2:120] -A logflags -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 1/sec --hashlimit-burst 10 --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name lograte -j LOG --log-prefix "logflags DROP " --log-level 6 --log-ip-options
[2:120] -A logflags -j DROP
[0:0] -A logreject -j reject
[0:0] -A reject -m addrtype --src-type BROADCAST -j DROP
[0:0] -A reject -s 224.0.0.0/4 -j DROP
[0:0] -A reject -p igmp -j DROP
[19:5148] -A reject -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
[0:0] -A reject -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
[0:0] -A reject -p icmp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-unreachable
[0:0] -A reject -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
[0:0] -A sfilter -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 1/sec --hashlimit-burst 10 --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name lograte -j LOG --log-prefix "sfilter DROP " --log-level 6
[0:0] -A sfilter -j DROP
[0:0] -A shorewall -m recent --set --name %CURRENTTIME --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource
[147356:24676752] -A sshok-fw -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[572:34348] -A sshok-fw -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m comment --comment SSH -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A tcpflags -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,PSH,URG -g logflags
[1:60] -A tcpflags -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -g logflags
[1:60] -A tcpflags -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -g logflags
[0:0] -A tcpflags -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -g logflags
[0:0] -A tcpflags -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -g logflags
[0:0] -A tcpflags -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,PSH,ACK FIN,PSH -g logflags
[0:0] -A tcpflags -p tcp -m tcp --sport 0 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -g logflags
[43:1804] -A ~log0 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 1/sec --hashlimit-burst 10 --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name lograte -j LOG --log-prefix "fw-net DROP " --log-level 6
[43:1804] -A ~log0 -j DROP
[1120:52679] -A ~log1 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 1/sec --hashlimit-burst 10 --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name lograte -j LOG --log-prefix "net-fw DROP " --log-level 6
[1120:52679] -A ~log1 -j DROP
[0:0] -A ~log2 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 1/sec --hashlimit-burst 10 --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name lograte -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT DROP " --log-level 6
[0:0] -A ~log2 -j DROP
[0:0] -A ~log3 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 1/sec --hashlimit-burst 10 --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name lograte -j LOG --log-prefix "OUTPUT DROP " --log-level 6
[0:0] -A ~log3 -j DROP
[0:0] -A ~log4 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-upto 1/sec --hashlimit-burst 10 --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name lograte -j LOG --log-prefix "FORWARD DROP " --log-level 6
[0:0] -A ~log4 -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Oct 27 16:43:40 2023
```

Comment: Sounds like your interpretation of the log files is wrong. This is what I would expect for packet based logging as opposed to connection / socket based logging.

Comment: @symcbean You are probably right, and it was to understand that I asked the question. I am very far from mastering the field. I needed to know if this revealed a configuration error on my part or if it was indeed normal as it seems.

Comment: Is there a web link to the question you asked on the mailing list please

Comment: You could provide the current resulting ruleset (`iptables-save -c`), so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @ChrisDavies For some reason, the message does not appear (yet) in the archives https://sourceforge.net/p/shorewall/mailman/shorewall-users/ probably too recent.
Personally, I access it via nntp through gmane (gmane.comp.security.shorewall) and the message in question is MiD <uhcp93$17n$1@ciao.gmane.io>

Comment: @A.B post edited

Comment: I can see INVALID packets are dropped before having a chance to be REJECT-ed, as should be. That was the thing I wanted to see, and as it's in place I have no more idea.

Comment: @A.B I think what you describe here is the consequence of adding dropInvalid to REJECT_DEFAULT, which I have since removed. In your opinion, do I risk side effects (legitimate connection lost) if I put NotSyn(DROP) all all tcp in rules ?

Comment: Check the warning: https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#REJECT_(IPv4-specific)  .

Comment: @A.B But, it's DROP, not REJECT...

Comment: I know about iptables but not about shorewall. So I don't understand your sentence. Both "which I have since removed" (dropInvalid or REJECT_DEFAULT? Was the question updated to reflect changes done?) and "NotSyn(DROP) ". So I have no opinion.

Comment: @A.B Ok. If you don't know shorewall, you obviously can't answer my last question. To be clear, it was suggested to me to add dropInvalid to REJECT_DEFAULT, and it is following this that I provided you with the result of iptables-save. But as this was clearly not the solution to my problem, I then returned to the default REJECT_DEFAULT, therefore removing the addition of dropInvalid. Thank you for your help. You helped me see things more clearly, but actually, my questions relate more to shorewall syntax.